# WEBAPI E CERTIFICADO A3 - TOKEN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, certificado-digital, token

Alguém aqui consegue usar certificado tipo A3 por uma WEBAPI ?

Pois quando testo ela em debug (ou seja, local), funciona tudo normal. Mas se eu compilar, e colocar no aplicativo IIS, fica me retornando que não existe nenhum certificado.
Alguém já passou por isso ?

Segue o Código, ( projeto Class Library )

```
public X509Certificate2 SelecionarCertificado(string serieCertDigital)
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
            ok = true;
            try
            {
                X509Certificate2Collection certificatesSel = null;
                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true).Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, true);

                if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(serieCertDigital)))
                {
                    certificatesSel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(certificates, "Certificados Digitais", "Selecione o Certificado Digital para uso no aplicativo", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
                    if ((certificatesSel.Count == 0))
                    {
                        certificate.Reset();
                        //Throw New Exception("Nenhum certificado digital foi selecionado ou o certificado selecionado está com problemas.")
                        mensagem += "Nenhum certificado digital foi selecionado ou o certificado selecionado está com problemas.";
                        ok = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        certificate = certificatesSel[0];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    certificatesSel = certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serieCertDigital, true);
                    if ((certificatesSel.Count == 0))
                    {
                        certificate.Reset();
                        mensagem += "Certificado digital não encontrado  " + certificates.Count.ToString();
                        ok = false;
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        certificate = certificatesSel[0];
                    }
                }
                store.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                mensagem += "Falha detectada ao verificar o certificado";
                ok = false;
                return null;
            }

            return certificate;
        }
```

Comment: Já tive esse problema, o que acontece é que o IIS não tem permissão de acesso ao computador local, somente aos certificados do modelo A3 instalados diretamente no servidor. Uma alternativa que adotei foi usar certificado A1, ai é só mandar direto para o servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde amigo.

O IIS possui um usuário específico que pertence a um grupo com acesso extremamente restrito as funcionalidades da máquina hospedeira.

Para resolver sua situação, basicamente você precisará configurar o usuário o IIS para ter acesso ao certificado.

Abaixo tem o Link de uma solução que, caso não resolva 100% seu questionamento, acredito que ao menos lhe dará um caminho a seguir.

Abraços.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate

Comment: Vou dar uma verificado e trago o retorno, Grato!